# Best method to output log content to listening port

Tags: linux, netcat

I am outputting content of a log via netcat to an application over the network. I don't know if what I'm doing is the most efficient, especially when I notice the netcat session becomes non-responsive. I have to stop netcat and start it again for the application to work again.

The command I run is:

```
/bin/tail -n1 -f /var/log/custom_output.log | /bin/nc -l -p 5020 --keep-open
```

This needs to run like this 24/7. Is this the most efficient way of doing it? How can I improve on it so I don't have to restart the process daily?

**EDIT**

So I realised that when the log is being rotated, netcat is locked onto a file that's not longer being written to. I can deal with this easily enough.

The question still stands. Is this the best way to do something like this?

Comment: How does the content reach that file?  If it's through syslog, then you should just configure syslog to log over UDP or TCP, since that's already a solved problem.

Comment: It's not syslog. It is Asterisk that writes specific values to this file on certain call events.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 6 years, but maybe someone will come in handy.

To account for log rotation, use **`tail`** with the `-F` flag.

### `nc` (aka `netcat`) variant

```bash
LOG_FILE="/var/log/custom_output.log"
PORT=5020
tail -n0 -F "$LOG_FILE" | nc -k -l -p $PORT
```

*Notes*:

- Flag `-k` in **`nc`** is analog to `--keep-open` in *"the OpenBSD rewrite of netcat"*;
- Multiple clients can connect to **`nc`** at the same time, but only the first one will be receive appended log lines;
- **`tail`** will run immediately, so it will collect appended log lines even if no client is connected. Thus, the first client can receive some buffered data - all log lines that have been appended since **`tail`** was run.

### `socat` variant

```bash
LOG_FILE="/var/log/custom_output.log"
PORT=5020
socat TCP-LISTEN:$PORT,fork,reuseaddr SYSTEM:"tail -n0 -F \"$LOG_FILE\" </dev/null"
```

*Note*: here **`socat`** will fork (clone itself) on each client connection and start a separate **`tail`** process. Thus:

- Each connected client will receive appended log lines at the same time;
- Clients will not receive any previously buffered by **`tail`** strings.

### additional

You can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` in the **`tail`** process by adding  `2>&1` (in both variants). In this case, clients will receive auxiliary message lines, e.g.:

- `tail: /var/log/custom_output.log: file truncated`;
- `tail: '/var/log/custom_output.log' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory` - printed when the log file has been removed or renamed, only if `-F` is used;
- `tail: '/var/log/custom_output.log' has appeared;  following new file` - printed when a new log file is created, only if `-F` is used.